# How to remove the white space without removing horizontal scrollbar when resized?

Tags: html, css

If I add the following css

```
html,body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This will solve the white-space problem but it will remove the horizontal scroll-bar and it is applied 100% width whatever the size of window but my site consists of fixed width. What can I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `min-width` to achieve what you are looking for.

**For Instance,**

```
html,body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
min-width:xxpx; /* enter a pixel value more than 1px that distorts the layout on resize */
}
```

***PS:** xxpx is a representative value. Use that value that is ideal for your issue resolve.*

Comment: sorry, this is also not showing the horizontal scroll bar when resized window.

Comment: by the way what is causing to be like this?

Comment: Strange. This should have resolved your issue. As `min-width` property does serve the purpose of what you are looking for. - @C-link

Comment: Yeah! I also think that it should work. but didn't. you can check yourself on live site.

Comment: Yes, it works for me. Make the below change in your css to make it work. `html body {
font-size: 13px 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
min-width: 1024px; 
}` - @C-link

Comment: Oh, yeah! It's working just in html body{} but not in html, body{} why?

Comment: It works for me, `html, body {
font-size: 13px 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
min-width: 1024px;
}` - @C-link